# Validacion previa usando el formulario de CreateView

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Estoy usando las vistas genéricas de Django para registrar/ingresar un producto, la idea o la duda es como puedo evaluar previamente dicho formulario enviado a su vista, mi código para crear es el siguiente:

```
class CrearProducto(CreateView):

    model = Producto
    form_class = ProductoForm
    template_name = "administrador/crear_producto.html"
    success_url = "/productos/administrar_productos"

@receiver(post_save, sender=Producto)
def GrabarMovimientos(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs ):

    producto_actual = Producto.objects.get(nombre=instance.nombre)

    movimiento = Movimientos(
        tipo = 1,
        proveedor = instance.proveedor,
        producto = producto_actual,
        bodega = instance.bodega,
        vunitario_promedio = float(instance.precio),
        #responsable = usuario,
        vunitario_compra = float(instance.precio),
        cant_ingreso = instance.cantidad,
        tot_ingreso = float(instance.cantidad) * float(instance.precio),
        tot_saldo = float(instance.cantidad) * float(instance.precio),
        cant_saldo = instance.cantidad,
    )
    movimiento.save()
```

En la vista `CreateView` guardo los productos lo cual hace bien una vez grabado los datos realizo un callback a `GrabarMovimientos` esta se encarga de registrar un movimiento para el manejo de Kardex, también lo hace bien, la cuestión es cómo validar dentro del `CreateView` que cumpla con ciertos requisitos, dentro de mi formulario uso la cantidad la cual no debe exceder cierto límite definido previamente.

Esta es la validación que me gustaría hacer, si cumple la validacion guardarla caso contrario retornar el formulario con un mensaje de error.

**Actualizacion**

Este sería el código de mi formulario:

```
class ProductoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Producto
        fields =[
            'nombre',
            'imagen',
            'descripcion',
            'precio',
            'iva_1',
            'iva_2',
            'iva_3',
            'cantidad',
            'cantidad_minima',
            'codigo',
            'cod_auxiliar',
            'medida',
            'bodega',
            'espacio',
            'proveedor',
            'categoria',
            'estado',
            'lote',
            'fec_fabricacion',
            'fec_caducidad',
        ]
        labels = {
            'nombre':'Nombre',
            'imagen':'Imagen',
            'descripcion':'Descripción',
            'precio':'Precio',
            'iva_1':'Impuesto 1',
            'iva_2':'Impuesto 2',
            'iva_3':'Impuesto 3',
            'cantidad':'Cantidad',
            'cantidad_minima':'Stock  minimo',
            'codigo':'Código Fabricante',
            'cod_auxiliar': 'Código Auxiliar',
            'medida':'Medida',
            'bodega':'Bodega',
            'espacio':'Espacio',
            'proveedor':'Proveedor',
            'categoria':'Categorias',
            'estado':'Estado',
            'lote': 'Lote',
            'fec_fabricacion': 'Fec. Fabricación',
            'fec_caducidad':'Fec. Caducidad',
        }
        widgets = {
            'nombre':forms.TextInput(attrs={"class":"text-capitalize form-control", 'required':'required'}),
            'descripcion':forms.TextInput(attrs={"class":"form-control", 'required':'required'}),
            'precio': forms.TextInput(attrs={"class": "form-control", 'required':'required'}),
            #'iva': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control input-sm', 'required':'required'}),
            'cantidad':forms.TextInput(attrs={"class":"form-control", 'required':'required'}),
            'cantidad_minima':forms.TextInput(attrs={"class":"form-control", 'required':'required'}),
            'codigo':forms.TextInput(attrs={"class":"form-control", 'required':'required'}),
            'cod_auxiliar':forms.TextInput(attrs={"class":"form-control", 'required':'required'}),
            'medida':forms.Select(attrs={"class":"form-control", 'required':'required'}),
            'bodega':forms.Select(attrs={"class":"form-control", 'required':'required'}),
            'espacio': forms.Select(attrs={"class": "form-control", 'required': 'required'}),
            'proveedor':forms.Select(attrs={"class":"form-control", 'required':'required'}),
            'lote': forms.TextInput(attrs={"class": "form-control", 'required':'required'}),
            'fec_fabricacion': forms.TextInput(attrs={"class": "form-control", 'required':'required', 'type':'date'}),
            'fec_caducidad': forms.TextInput(attrs={"class": "form-control", 'required':'required', 'type':'date'}),
            'estado': forms.Select(attrs={"class": "form-control"})
        }
```

La cantidad del producto debe validarse en base a un parámetro establecido en **espacio** del productos. El modelo es:

```
class Espacio(models.Model):

    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    descripcion = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    codigo = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    fila = models.ForeignKey(Fila, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    columna = models.ForeignKey(Columna, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cantidad_minima = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    cantidad_maxima = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    estado = models.IntegerField(choices=estado_choices, default=Activo)

    #def __str__(self):
    #    return self.nombre +self.fila + self+columna
    def __str__(self):
        return '%s Fila(%s) Columna(%s)' % (self.nombre, self.fila, self.columna)
```

Comment: Diego, eso tienes que validarlo en `ProductoForm`, tal vez puedas mostrar el código de tu formulario para ayudarte.

Comment: @César listo ya actualize mi pregunta gracias..

Comment: No entiendo cómo es que se amarra el Producto con el Espacio para validar la cantidad.

Comment: dentro del model producto tiene el campo espacio el cual es la clave foranea de el model Espacio... con ello vincula o relaciona la misma

Comment: A lo que me refiero es, para validar la cantidad de un producto en tu formulario, este campo `cantidad` tiene que estar entre `Espacio.cantidad_minima` y `Espacio.cantidad_maxima`. ¿Es así?

Comment: exacto eso es lo que deseo validar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar el método `clean()` del formulario para validarlo:

```
class ProductoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # ...

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(ProductoForm, self).clean()
        cantidad = cleaned_data.get('cantidad')
        espacio_id = cleaned_data.get('espacio')

        # En este punto no estoy seguro si "espacio" contiene el ID del espacio
        # o un objeto. Si es un ID entonces puedes hacer un query a la base de
        # datos
        espacio = Espacio.objects.get(id=espacio_id)

        if cantidad < espacio.cantidad_minima or cantidad > espacio.cantidad_maxima:
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                'La cantidad no es correcta'
            )
```

Ahora, ten en cuenta que los errores creados desde el método `clean()` son accesibles desde `form.non_field_errrors`. Por lo tanto, en tu template deberías mostrarlos así:

```
{% if form.non_field_errors %}
    {% for error in form.non_field_errors %}
        {{ error }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: muchas gracias.. solo una pregunta esta validacion servira en una ventana modal que traigo mediante una url como view....es decirl el form de productos la muestro en una modal que cargo mediante una url

Comment: @DiegoAvila si es un modal, imagino que tendrías que hacerlo usando AJAX